# how to work with on onResume() in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 activities .First time I run the application I have to open the popup in Activity 1 when I first to start the application. After that I want to go activity 2 and make some changes there. Again i come back to Activity 2 and i don't want to open the popup. But the problem is whenever i comeback to 1st Activity the popup is open.How to solve this issues?

Here is my code.

```
db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Inspector where ActiveStatus= '1' AND FollowFlag ='1'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String strInspectoreName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Inspector_name"));
                String strInspectorId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Inspector_Id"));

                if(!strInspectorId.equals(str_LoginUserId))
                {
                    inspector_ArrayList.add(strInspectoreName);
                    Log.e("Post ", " Total FollowUp Users !!!" + strInspectoreName);
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        int countFollowUp = inspector_ArrayList.size();
        Log.e("Post ", " Total countFollowUp Users !!!" + countFollowUp);

        if( countFollowUp == 0)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomActionActivity.this);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);

            Button followStart = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_FollowStart);
            followStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(CustomActionActivity.this, Filter_Screen.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_Dissmiss);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Here is my onResume() in Activity 1st

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(" Activity ", " Resume !!! ");
        Log.e("From ", " Filter 222");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        booleanValue_one = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("LISTVIEW_EVENT_ONE", false);
        booleanValue_two = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("LISTVIEW_EVENT_TWO", false);
        Log.e("", "booleanValue_one=" + booleanValue_one + " booleanValue_two=" + booleanValue_two);


        if (booleanValue_one == true || booleanValue_two == true)
        {
            GetAllActivityDetails task = new GetAllActivityDetails();
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            Log.e(" booleanValue_one "," = " + booleanValue_one +" After completing async task !!!!");
            updatedDownLoadStatus();
        }

        if (booleanValue_one == false && booleanValue_two == false)
        {
            populateList();
        }

    }
```

Here is my 2nd activity onBackPressed() -> go to 1st Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent a = new Intent(Filter_Screen.this, CustomActionActivity.class);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(a);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
}
```

Comment: onBackPressed() method do not start activity.

Comment: then how to goto back 1st activity.

Comment: @override public void onBackPressed() { super.onBackPressed();   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom); }

Answer (score 0):

Make A boolean Key `boolean key=true;` and use that boolean key to display the Popup in `onResume()` and in `onCreate()` make that boolean false

`onResume()` also call when activity start and when you come back it call again

Answer (score 0):

Your onResume() is called everytime you go back to the running activity and also the first time you create the activity thats why it wil run the code evrytime you go back to the activity. 
To resolve this problem you should put the code from your onResume in your onCreate that way it only runs when the activity is first created.

For more info and to fully understand the lifecycle of an activity check : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#lifecycle-states

Comment: I don't understand .

Comment: @p.ld well if I correctly understood your question you want the popup to be opened only the first time the app is launched is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It this is a fist time running thing like an introduction of collect some user information, Save the state to shared preferences and use that to check and allow or disallow the pop-ups accordingly.